S3 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I'm using JavaScript AWS SDK to upload a file to S3
const AWS = window.AWS;
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: this.credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: this.credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    region_config: "us-west-1",
    sessionToken: this.credentials.SessionToken
});

let s3 = new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: "v4"
});
if (this.selectedFilesToUpload) {
    s3.upload(
        {
            Key: 'Files/068VC000001DrynYAC006VC000004zSwSDGF.pdf',
            Bucket: 'xxxxx',
            ContentType: 'application/pdf',
            Body: this.selectedFilesToUpload
        },
        err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success");
            }
        }
    );
}

But I'm receiving CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/Files/068VC000001DrynYAC006VC000004zSwSDGF.pdf' from origin 'https://yyyyy.salesforce-experience.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I already update S3 bucket CORS setting, but without any results:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]


For Access-Control-Allow-Origin to work, you need to specify the domain which you allows. You can try:
"ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://yyyyy.salesforce-experience.com"
        ]

